# Gitlab redirects to root domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, gitlab

i'm experiencing an strange issue with gitlab (hosted by myself). When i want to access gitlab, it redirects me to the root domain. (Gitlab is hostet on an subdomain, root domain host is different from gitlab host).

After some search i didn't found a solution, so iam asking the question, how to fix this?

Some information:

- External URL is set to the correct one in the configuration files (gitlab.rb & gitlab.yml)
- Result of **sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check** can be found here: http://pastebin.com/FCXfGM3u
- Result of **sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info** can be found here: http://pastebin.com/93t0n36q

If more information is needed feel free to ask.

Comment: What are your DNS records?

Comment: the root domain has an a record to my root server the gitlab domain is an cname to my dyndns domain, which is hosted at my home.

Comment: You say both hosts differ. There has to be atleast another A record for your GitLab instance.

Comment: I have an domain, which has an A record, this a record points to my root server. For my home i got an dyndns domain, so the gitlab domain is an subdomain of my domain with an cname record to the dyndns domain.

Comment: You can test it by yourself: the root domain is [link](http://rd9.eu) the gitlab domain is [link](http://git.rd9.eu)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/git.rd9.eu) and [this](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/rd9.eu). Your DNS records resolve your git.* subdomain to the root domain.

Comment: Am i stupid, or is my result different from yours? [link](http://pastebin.com/VwGu9YnZ)

Comment: What I am trying to say is that your DNS records don't look correct.

Comment: things get even stranger [link](http://git.rd9.eu/users/sign_in)

Answer (score 1):

I found the error... 
It was my fault. I had set the homepage in gitlab to my "home page", not to the gitlab home page. When i wanted to access gitlab, if not logged in, i was redirected to my homepage. not to gitlab.

Comment: Btw., you can accept your own answer (it'll mark your question solved and award you reputation).